# Missing one-pixel row while transfering image with TCP socket

Tags: python, tcp

I'm facing strange error right now, I have python script, that is sending/receiving data using TCP socket, everything works fine, but when I'm trying to download image with this script, it will download it, but there is a missing one-pixel row. Any ideas on how to fix it?

**Server download script:**

```
    def download(self, cmd):
        try:
            self.c.send(str.encode(cmd))
            command,filename=cmd.split(' ')
            nFile = open(filename, 'wb')
            i = self.c.recv(1024)
            while not ('complete' in str(i)):   
                nFile.write(i)
                i = self.c.recv(1024)
            nFile.close()
            self.reset = True
            print('\nGot that file')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

**Client upload script:**

```
   def upload(self, filename):
    try:
        fd = open(filename, 'rb')
        data = fd.read(1024)
        while (data):
            self.s.sendall(data)
            data = fd.read(1024)
        self.s.send(str.encode('complete'))
        fd.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**EXAMPLE** *- You can see, that last row of pixels is missing:* [image]

**SOLUTION(1):** *It's not a solution, just workaround, use the other one!*

> What happens if you remove the complete part of the payload before
>   writing the last chunk of data to nFile? – mtrw

The problem was with sending 'complete' string to the server, because the script had not enough time to get all bytes from the image. So one way to fix this is to add **sleep(0.2)** to the script.

**Client upload script:**

```
   def upload(self, filename):
try:
    fd = open(filename, 'rb')
    data = fd.read(1024)
    while (data):
        self.s.sendall(data)
        data = fd.read(1024)
    sleep(0.2)
    self.s.send(str.encode('complete'))
    fd.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**SOLUTION(2):**

> TCP is a stream protocol with no message boundaries. This means that
>   multiple sends can be received in one recv call, or one send can be
>   received in multiple recv calls.
>
> The delay work-around may not work reliably. You need to delimit
>   messages in the stream.
>
> – Maxim Egorushkin

**Server download script:**

```
try:
    msg_header = self.c.recv(4)
    while len(msg_header) != 4:
        msg_header += self.c.recv(4 - len(msg_header))
    file_len = struct.unpack('<I', msg_header)[0]
    nFile = open(filename, 'wb')
    data = self.c.recv(file_len)
    while len(data) != file_len:
        data += self.c.recv(file_len - len(data))
    nFile.write(data)
    nFile.close()
    print('\nGot that file')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Client upload script:**

```
try:
    file_len = os.stat(filename).st_size
    msg_header = struct.pack('<I', file_len)
    self.s.sendall(msg_header)
    fd = open(filename, 'rb')
    data = fd.read(file_len)
    while (data):
        self.s.sendall(data)
        data = fd.read(file_len)
    fd.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `complete` part of the payload before writing the last chunk of data to `nFile`?

Comment: Wow... Such an easy fix, I feel so dumb right now. But still, I don't get why is actually that 'create' word parsing into the image file, when it has to check if that received byte is 'download' and if it is it has to stop the write session.

Comment: I guess the extra bytes are confusing the image parser. The image header probably has some information on the expected number of bytes, and the file being bigger than the header specified causes strange behavior. The image display might have crashed, might have shown the correct thing by ignoring the extra bytes, really impossible to say what will happen

Comment: Conversion to `int` in `int(file_len[0])` shouldn't be necessary, it unpacked an `int` already. You should also check the return value of `send` because it is not guaranteed to send the entire buffer. In other words, implement `sendall` function with a loop.

Comment: Well, file_len is tuple when I unpack it,  at least in my program.

Comment: @JanVodenka Yep, `unpack` returns a tuple, you are right. But the cast shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: So I've changed it to this `file_len = int(struct.unpack('<I', msg_header)[0])`, anyways, thanks for all, you helped me a lot!

Comment: @JanVodenka I am saying that `int(...)` bit is unnecessary. Just `file_len = struct.unpack('<I', msg_header)[0]`. It is a small thing though...

Comment: Since it downloads into a file, you may like to write each received chunk into the file immediately, rather than downloading the entire file into RAM first by concatenating all chunks. If you do so, then it should write into a temporary file with a different name first (but in the same directory, e.g. filename~, so that `os.rename` doesn't need to move the file onto another filesystem) and only `os.rename` it to the required name after the entire file has been written (best in `with` code block), so that the file is complete if it exists.

Comment: Well, I've used `with` for both write and read function and it's working nearly perfectly. I've created the script, that is able to download folder with all subfolders/files in it, but I've found one problem, when I'm trying to download a file that is more than 1 GB big, it's throwing an error that it cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer. Is it possible, that `struct` cant accept a file of this size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem was with sending 'complete' string to the server, because the script had not enough time to get all bytes from the image. So one way to fix this is to add sleep(0.2) to the script.

TCP is a stream protocol with no message boundaries. This means that multiple `send`s can be received in one `recv` call, or one `send` can be received in multiple `recv` calls.

The delay work-around may not work reliably. You need to delimit messages in the stream.

There are 2 common ways of delimiting messages in a stream:

1. Prefix messages with a header.
2. End messages with a suffix.

---

Since you are sending binary data any suffix can naturally be present in the payload. Unless the suffix is longer than the payload, which isn't practical.

Hence, what you may like to do here is prefix a fixed-size header to your payload. In this particular case, a header with a 4-byte binary file length would suffice. E.g.:

```
file_len = os.stat(filename).st_size
msg_header = struct.pack('<I', file_len)
self.s.sendall(msg_header)
```

The receiver needs to read the header first:

```
msg_header = self.s.recv(4)
while len(msg_header) != 4:
    msg_header += self.s.recv(4 - len(msg_header))
file_len = struct.unpack('<I', msg_header)
```

And then read exactly `file_len` from the socket.

Knowing the size of the file being received also allows you to preallocate the buffer to avoid memory reallocations and/or preallocate the entire file to minimize disk fragmentation or avoid out of disk space error after the file transfer has started.

Comment: So I've successfully managed to get the size of the file, but how can I now set that while loop, to keep looping till the whole image is downloaded? I'm missing the point of that msg_header, it looks like it always has 4 bytes inside, so a loop is never active. Could you explain it a little bit more, please?

Comment: @JanVodenka `recv(n)` may read less than `n`, this is why `recv` must be called in a loop until exactly `n` bytes are read. People often extract this loop as `recvall` function. There is a high chance that small `n` is read in one `recv` call and that `while` loop doesn't execute, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Well, I've managed to get it working, edited the solution then, thanks for the advice!