# What is the best way to determine packet size with recv()?

Tags: c, sockets, send, recv

Extremely new to socket programming and C in general. I am trying to write a basic program to send and receive data between two machines. I understand that `recv` will not get all your data at once -- you essentially have to loop it until it has read the whole message.

In lieu of just setting a limit on both machines, I have created a simple `Message` struct on the client side:

```
struct Message {
    size_t length;
    char contents[1024 - sizeof(size_t)];
} message; 
message.length = sizeof(struct Message);
message.contents = information_i_want_to_send;
```

When it arrives at the server, I have `recv` read into a buffer: `received = recv(ioSock, &buffer, 1024, 0)` (Which coincidentally is the same size as my Message struct -- but assuming it wasn't...).

I then extract `Message.length` from the buffer like this:

```
size_t messagelength;
messagelength = *((size_t *) &buffer);
```

Then I loop `recv` into the buffer while `received < messagelength`.
This works, but I can't help feeling it's really ugly and it feels hacky. (Especially if the first `recv` call reads less than `sizeof(size_t)` or the machines are different bit architectures, in which case the size_t cast won't work..). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you should check out `htonl`, `ntohl` and the other functions in that range

Comment: Messages are only present in datagram protocols, e.g. UDP. There are no messages in TCP, you need to delimit messages yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271376/412080

Comment: Re "*I understand that recv will not get all your data at once -- you essentially have to loop it until it has read the whole message.*", With TCP, yes. With UDP, I think `recv` gets exactly one datagram.

Comment: You're on the right track but you should not use a `struct` as a network protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a fixed-size message, so you can use something like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// Returns the number of bytes read.
// EOF was reached if the number of bytes read is less than requested.
// On error, returns -1 and sets errno.
ssize_t recv_fixed_amount(int sockfd, char *buf, size_t size) {
   if (size > SSIZE_MAX) {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return -1;
   }

   ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
   while (size > 0) {
      ssize_t rv = recv(sockfd, buf, size, 0); 
      if (rv < 0)
         return -1;
      if (rv == 0)
         return bytes_read;

      size -= rv;
      bytes_read += rv;
      buf += rv;
   }

   return bytes_read;
}
```

It would be used something like this:

```
typedef struct {
   uint32_t length;
   char contents[1020];
} Message;

Message message;

ssize_t bytes_read = recv_fixed_amount(sockfd, &(message.length), sizeof(message.length));
if (bytes_read == 0) {
   printf("EOF reached\n");
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

if (bytes_read < 0) {
   perror("recv");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bytes_read != sizeof(message.length)) {
   fprintf(stderr, "recv: Premature EOF.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

bytes_read = recv_fixed_amount(sockfd, &(message.content), sizeof(message.content));
if (bytes_read < 0) {
   perror("recv");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bytes_read != msg_size) {
   fprintf(stderr, "recv: Premature EOF.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notes:

- `size_t` is not going to be the same everywhere, so I switched to a `uint32_t`.
- I read the fields independently because the padding within the struct can vary between implementations. They would need to be sent that way as well.
- The receiver is populating `message.length` with the information from the stream, but doesn't actually use it.
- A malicious or buggy sender could provide a value for `message.length` that's too large and crash the receiver (or worse) if it doesn't validate it. Same goes for `contents`. It might not be NUL-terminated if that's expected.

---

But what if the length wasn't fixed? Then the sender would need to somehow communicate how much the reader needs to read. A common approach is a length prefix.

```
typedef struct {
   uint32_t length;
   char contents[];
} Message;

uint32_t contents_size;
ssize_t bytes_read = recv_fixed_amount(sockfd, &contents_size, sizeof(contents_size));
if (bytes_read == 0) {
   printf("EOF reached\n");
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

if (bytes_read < 0) {
   perror("recv");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bytes_read != sizeof(contents_size)) {
   fprintf(stderr, "recv: Premature EOF.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Message *message = malloc(sizeof(Message)+contents_size);
if (!message) {
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

message->length = contents_size;

bytes_read = recv_fixed_amount(sockfd, &(message->contents), contents_size);
if (bytes_read < 0) {
   perror("recv");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (bytes_read != contents_size) {
   fprintf(stderr, "recv: Premature EOF.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notes:

- `message->length` contains the size of `message->contents` instead of the size of the structure. This is far more useful.

---

Another approach is to use a sentinel value. This is a value that tells the reader the message is over. This is what the NUL that terminates C strings is. This is more complicated because you don't know how much to read in advance. Reading byte-by-byte is too expensive, so one normally uses a buffer.

```
 while (1) {
     extend_buffer_if_necessary();
     recv_into_buffer();
     while (buffer_contains_a_sentinel()) {
        // This also shifts the remainder of the buffer's contents.
        extract_contents_of_buffer_up_to_sentinel();
        process_extracted_message();      
     }
 }
```

The advantage of using a sentinel value is that one doesn't need to know the length of the message in advance (so the sender can start sending it before it's fully created.)

The disadvantage is the same as for C strings: The message can't contain the sentinel value unless some form of escaping mechanism is used. Between this and the complexity of the reader, you can see why a length prefix is usually preferred over a sentinel value. :)

---

Finally, there's a better solution than sentinel values for large messages that you want to start sending before they are fully created: A sequence of length-prefixed chunks. One keeps reading chunks until a chunk of size 0 is encountered, signaling the end.

HTTP supports both length-prefixed messages (in the form of `Content-Length: <length>` header) and this approach (in the form of the [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)).

Comment: I see, thank you. This is far cleaner than my method. So it seems like no matter the case, to send data cleanly you need to have some point of agreement/fixed parameter? I.e. in your example, the size of the message prefix is something agreed upon by both sender and receiver.

Comment: Yes, when using a stream protocol (e.g. TCP, or reading a series of record from a file), everything must be of some agreed-upon size and byte endianess if that information isn't in the message itself.

Comment: Even when dealing with datagrams (UDP) or reading a single record from a file, you still need to have an agreement of the size of the fields (if there are more than one) and the endianness of those fields.

Comment: I made some improvements, and added an alternative to length-prefix.

Comment: Fixed a bug. (Thanks to chux)

Comment: ikegami, Do you see any real possibility the the recipient of data is out-of-phase with the sender? Had even 1 byte been missed - somehow, all following traffic would be misinterpreted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, That's usually a concern for link-level protocols (e.g. PPP), not application-layer protocols (e.g. HTTP). Slippage at the application layer would indicate a bug in the code. Whereas noise can cause it at the link layer.

Answer (score -1):

There are Two ways to do that...

1.)
Use Binary Synchronous protocol. (Use of STX - Start of Text and ETX - End of Text ) for identification of the Text start and end.

2.) 
Attach the number of bytes of data being sent at the start of Data. The socket will read those number of bytes and will get the number of bytes to be received from the socket. Then read all data and get the amount of data required.

Hmm... Seems tough...?? Let me give you an example.

Actual Data need to be sent: ABCDEFGHIJ

New Data format : 0010ABCDEFGHIJ

Data required in server side: ABCDE

recv function will read the first 4 bytes to get the number of bytes of actual data(In loop untill it gets 4 bytes):

```
int received1= recv(ioSock, recvbuf, 4, 0);
```

As per the above case, 'recvbuf' will be 0010 converted to an integer will give value as '10' which can be stored in some integer variable. So we have :

```
int toReadVal = 10
```

Now all we need is to read these 10 digits in next recv call :

```
int received= recv(ioSock, recvbuf1, toReadVal, 0);
```

Finally, we get the value of recvbuf1 as ABCDEFGHIG. Now you can truncate the value as per your requirement.

Comment: There are several other ways to do it. STX and ETX mean start/end of *transmission*, not 'text'. No `recv()` call is guaranteed to fill the buffer. Your answer doesn't extend the OP's code in any useful way,

Comment: I liked the mention of STX/ETX, especially in comparison to attach the length of the message in the message itself.

Comment: @user207421 ... The whole google world explains stx/etx as start/end of text. BTW recv() function doesn't guaranteed to fill buffer thats why there is a 'NOTE' in the brackets provided for looping the logic. We can explain the logic but can not provide all the validation and code. This might help to get the proper solution.

Comment: Re "*The whole google world explains stx/etx as start/end of text.*", Including [UNICODE](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf), at least when referring to U+0002 and U+0003

Comment: @ikegami Don't grep the keyword 'NOTE'. The sentence is 'there is a 'NOTE' in the brackets provided for looping the logic'. :-p

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but there's a lot that's unclear about your post. I started fixing the issues, but it was just too much work at this point.